# Replace a word with a word in the URL string

Tags: filters, actions

I'm trying to replace a word on every page for example "Denver" with a word from a URL string, so I'll have like `?city=Atlanta` in the URL.  So I was thinking of using PHP's GET to just get the city from the URL string and [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace it, but which action/hook in WordPress do I have to attach it to?

The word will appear throughout the entire page, including title, logo description, content, footer, etc... so it can't just replace content only.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Filter Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/) -- there are filters like `the_content`, `the_title`, `wp_title`, etc. I'm not sure what you'd filter to get the logo description and footer -- you might need to delve into your theme's code.

Also, make sure you sanitize anything you get from `$_GET` -- *never ever* trust user-generated content.  See [Data Validation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) for more information.

Comment: Dang I was hoping there would be a way to search all text and not have to go through individual elements.

Comment: Each chunk of text -- the title, the content, etc -- is stored in a different field in the DB.  But most everything in WordPress has a filter that you can use.  Not all are documented in the Codex.  Another site that lists filters and hooks -- though it doesn't explain them, by and large -- is Adam Brown's [WordPress hooks database](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/).

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace` will make a mess of any unlucky markup on the page since it will replace matching text inside of markup or inside of URLs.

What you want is a modified versions of an answer I gave to another question [about highlighting search terms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97958/highlight-search-results-in-function-php/97965#97965). The change would be to the `highlight_search_term` function. You just need to alter it to use the `$_GET` data instead of the search data.

```
function highlight_search_term($text){
  if(!empty($_GET['city']){
    $keys = strip_tags($_GET['city']); // nominal validation
    $pattern = '/<[^>].*?>/i';
    preg_match_all($pattern,$text,$matches);
    $placeholders = array();
    foreach ($matches[0] as $v) {
      $placeholders[] = highlight_search_term_placeholders();
    }
    $text = preg_replace_callback($pattern,'highlight_search_term_cb',$text);
    $pattern2 = '/(' . $keys .')/iu';
    $text = preg_replace($pattern2, ' <span class="search-term">\1</span> ', $text);
    $text = preg_replace($placeholders,$matches[0],$text);
  }
  return $text;
}
```

Comment: Does this still need to be attached to each filter, the_content, the_title, etc...?  Also, where would I put which word I want to replace? If the target word is "Denver", title tag might contain "The Denver Website", so I'd only want to replace "Denver".

Comment: Yes, it needs to be attached to the filters you want, at least. I only posted the altered code. You still need everything from the other answer.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll play around with it a bit and will update the post.